# Passing Jquery field value into Bootstrap Validator

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

Facing issues in invoking the Jquery variable into the Bootstrap validator. Declared a variable tempValue and what will be the syntax to use that variable into my custom function 2

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var tempValue = $('#firstName').val();
$('#registration').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        firstName: {
            validators: {
                stringLength: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 50,
                    message: 'First name cannot exceed 50 characters'
                },
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please enter your first name'
                },
                customFunction1: {
                    keyValue: customFunction2(tempValue)
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin has nothing to do with the BootStrap Validator plugin.  Edited.  Please be more careful when tagging.